# Apex Test Class - Simple Insert

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

Trying to teach myself Salesforce Development.

I created a Lightning Component for a Communities page to create a Lead.  The component works fine, simply calls the Apex class to insert the Lead.

However, I can't figure out how to write the test class required before this can be passed to production.

Here is the Apex Class to create the Lead:

```
public class LightningLeadCreatecls {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void createLead(Lead leadObj){
        insert leadObj; 
    }
}
```

I have written Apex Test Classes for Apex Classes that simply pull data with SELECT, but can't figure out how to create this test class.  It is at 0/2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No different as the example found in Salesforce's official site, try

```
@isTest 
private class LightningLeadCreateTest {
static testMethod void doTest() {
   // Insert Lead
   Lead l = new Lead(LastName='Test', Company='Test', Status='Open - Not Contacted');
   LightningLeadCreatecls.createLead(l);

   // Retrieve the Lead
   Lead verifyLead = [SELECT LastName FROM Lead LIMIT 1];

   // Test that Lead exist
   System.assertEquals('Test', verifyLead.LastName);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks.  I knew I had to get the class and method in there, just wasn't sure of the syntax.